# VBA scroll to text (search result)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function which searchs through all the textboxes in a file and when it finds the text it automatically scrolls the window to the shape that contains the text.

Is it possible to:

- a) scroll to the text, instead of the shape (scroll the page and center it on the search text result)
- b) if not possible, then scroll to the middle of the shape (now it's going to the top)

---

```
If InStr(LCase(sTemp), LCase(sFind)) <> 0 Then
  shp.Select

   With shp.Line
        .ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        .Weight = 5
   End With

    sFind2 = LCase(sFind)
        sTemp2 = LCase(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
        iPos2 = InStr(sTemp2, sFind2)
        If iPos2 > 0 Then
            With shp.TextFrame.Characters(Start:=iPos2, _
              Length:=Len(sFind2)).Font
                .Size = 35
            End With
        End If

    shp.Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = shp.TopLeftCell.Row
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = shp.TopLeftCell.Column

End If
```

Useless to say: I am not an expert, sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- a) you cannot scroll to a text. You can just scroll full rows and full columns.
- b) you can do that only approximately, because you can just scroll full rows and full columns.

Since `shp.TopLeftCell` finds the top left cell under the shape, you can try to use the height/width of the shape and cells to find the cell that is **approximately** in the middle of the shape.

```
'scroll additional rows
Dim CellHeights As Double
CellHeights = shp.TopLeftCell.Height
Dim iRow As Long
Do While CellHeights < shp.Height / 2
    CellHeights = CellHeights + shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(RowOffset:=iRow).Height
    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(RowOffset:=iRow).Row

'scroll additional columns
Dim CellWidths As Double
CellWidths = shp.TopLeftCell.Width
Dim iCol As Long
Do While CellWidths < shp.Width / 2
    CellWidths = CellWidths + shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=iCol).Width
    iCol = iCol + 1
Loop
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=iCol).Column
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work! It scrolls in a completely wrong place (right and down of the textbox) and I can barely see the textbox. It goes completely out of focus!

Comment: @Kuitogu67 Can you please include a screenshot of your sheet in your original question. Because in my test case this worked perfectly.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ses5gs  (before search)

https://prnt.sc/ses5lu   (result)

Comment: shp.Width / 20   and   shp.Height / 20 give much better results, no idea why!

Comment: @Kuitogu67 Well it did exactly what I expected: It scrolled to the center of the text box. The middle of the shape is now in the top left corner. That is actually what you asked for. Can you please show a last screenshot of what result you would have expected in that example?

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself clearly: I would like to have the middle of the textbox in the middle of the active screen.  Also about method a which you said not possible.. Would it be possible to locate the text in relation to the height of the textbox and go to that place? Or maybe count the rows of text, go to topleftcell and then scroll down the rows? Thanks anyway for what you already did!

Comment: @Kuitogu67 a) no, I don't see any soulution for this method at all you cannot locate the word in the text box, this depends on the font, fontsize and so on and you don't get enough data ouf of the text box to calculate the position.

Comment: @Kuitogu67 b) I guess this is not possible neither because if you want to center it in the window you would need to know how many visible rows/columns are in your window right now (to calculate the center position), and there is no method to determine that. Furthermore you cannot scroll into the negative so a shape in cell A2:B5 will never be possible to center in the window eg if the visible area is bigger like A1:M40. • So finally what you actually ask for is not possible to do (not even approximately).

Comment: Ok I will mark it as a solution anyway because by entering "shp.Width / 20 and shp.Height / 20 " I get very good results anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Kuitogu67 But note that you get this result just by random. Actually it is good by accident. Use another window size and the result is bad.

Comment: Thanks! I will tailor it to the screensize in case I change pc!

Comment: It's not about the screen size but the Excel window size (or more precise about the area of visible cells in the window). Eg showing/hiding the ribbon toolbar will already make a difference.